# Passing shellcode from Python as command line argument

Tags: python, utf-8, buffer-overflow

I am currently preparing a small presentation about computer security among my fellow students. To get them at least a bit excited I wanted to demonstrate how the wrong use of the strcpy-function inc C can be exploited.
This is the code of the vulnerable program:

```
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>
void function(char *buffer1)
{
 char buffer2[5];
 strcpy(buffer2,buffer1);
}

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
 function(argv[1]);
 return 0;
}
```

Just using the command line I was able to crash the application by calling it with

```
test.exe ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

Which gave me the correct 0x4D4C4B4A (MLKJ) for the EIP. It also works if I call it from Python:

```
os.system("test.exe ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
```

However, if I want to put an address instead of JKLM, like this:

```
 os.system("test.exe ABCDEFGHI\x75\x9a\x21\x1bNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
```

It gives me following output near the ESP on the Stack:

```
0028cca0  e4 21 d7 41 42 43 44 45-46 47 48 49 75 c2 9a 21  .!.ABCDEFGHIu..!
0028ccb0  1b 4e 4f 50 51 52 53 54-55 56 57 58 59 5a 00 00  .NOPQRSTUVWXYZ..
```

Here the 75 c2 9a 21 matters because it is almost what I expected, except the 0x1B, which is the ASCII Character for ESCAPE, is replaced by 0xC2.
When I change the order of the address, so it looks like this: \x21\x1b\x75\x9a, the 9a gets replaced by the same mysterious C2.
Does anyone know whats the matter with the code? Am I missing some basic point or is it some kind of protection against stack based buffer overflows?

Thanks,

Comment: Which version of Python are you using (2.x or 3.x)?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that: I am using Python 3.1 on Windows 7 64 bit

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your text is undergoing UTF-8 conversion. Note that your original bytes:

```
75 9a 21 1b
   ^^
```

are replaced by

```
75 c2 9a 21 1b
   ^^^^^
```

I've highlighted the UTF-8 encoded byte. If you're using Python 3, try:

```
os.system(b"test.exe ABCDEFGHI\x75\x9a\x21\x1bNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
```

The `b""` indicates that the data is a *byte* sequence, and shouldn't be converted from Unicode to the default encoding (which in your case seems to be UTF-8).

Comment: Hi, I tried that before, unfortunately it causes an Type error because the os.system() call expects a string, not bytes.

Comment: @AlexanderF: Perhaps you could try the `subprocess` module instead. I was able to successfully pass raw bytes through `subprocess.Popen(["test.exe", b"ABCDE"])`.

Comment: That does not work here, it says that the Type str does not support the buffer api.However, I was able to pass the desired bytes from another C program that uses the system() call.